# Getting the requester's socket inside an express route

Tags: express, socket.io

I want to send to every users the signal that a user has used a route, but not to this user. SocketIO has a "broadcast" function that does the trick just fine, but I don't know how (even if) I can have access to this variable inside the route function.
For example:

```js
app.post('/api', (req, res) => {

    // Doing stuff...

    socket.broadcast.emit('myAwesomeEvent');
    // Broadcast will send the signal to every users but the socket's owner

});
```

So, I don't know how to get this "broadcast" socket inside the route, if there's a middleware to get it, or even if it's possible. If it's not, how can I achieve my goal?
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Are you using any type of server-side session object already?

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

The way I am doing the same is first authenticating client's socket and giving the socket some temporary code.

Now whenever client is hitting the route, I expects socket-id and temporary code provided as above in all request.

Now using that socket-id, I send broadcast to all other.

You can modify the same logic as per your need.